# How to read Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am trying to read Excel file in C# .net core 2.2. For reading Excel I am using [EpPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). I have taken reference from [File uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2). I have Api like this

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<ReappropiationAccountViewModel>> Post(IFormFile file)
 {
        return Ok(await Mediator.Send(new SaveReappropriationAccountCommand { ReappropiationAccountFile = file }));
 }
```

And my command is like this

```
public class SaveReappropriationAccountCommand : IRequest<ReappropiationAccountViewModel>
{
    public IFormFile ReappropiationAccountFile { get; set; }
}
```

And in my handler I am trying to read Excel like this

```
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await request.ReappropiationAccountFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

                int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;

                for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                    {
                        var rowValue = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

But I am not been able to read the uploaded Excel as it throws `InvalidDataException` in `using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream))` line.

Exception message:

> InvalidDataException: The file is not an valid Package file. If the file is encrypted, please supply the password in the constructor.

Everything seems absolutely right but not been able to read the Excel data. Trying to read this Excel file:

[image]

My question is where am I going wrong?

Comment: it throws `InvalidDataException: The file is not an valid Package file. If the file is encrypted, please supply the password in the constructor.`

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Please attach the Excel file to your question so we can see it.

Comment: `using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream))` line throws an exception .  You mean Excel File?

Comment: Can you save the memory stream to a file again on the server and just check if that is still a valid excel file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your memory stream back to the beginning after writing it and before passing it to the ExcelPackage to read it:

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: Still the same issue persist